# Add a comma at the end of each returned value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This perfectly returns all the email in the column *regEmail* from the table *tblXUDUserRegistration*. 
 Now how can I get the same query with a comma (,) at the end of each value?

```
SELECT regEmail FROM [db182324492].[dbo182324492].[tblXUDUserRegistration]
```

IE.

```
someemail@myemail.com,
someemail@myemail2.com,
someemail@myemail3.com,
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like this:

```
SELECT regEmail + ',' AS regEmail
FROM [db182324492].[dbo182324492].[tblXUDUserRegistration]
```

Comment: This worked Andriy, thank for your help with this! I will add this as the answer shortly

Comment: how can you do this if the data is numbers?

Comment: @сꝛıϻѕοɴᴠᴇɴoϻ: Cast the number as a string, then concatenate it with the comma.